# WordPress website contains a space between menu and slider

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, slider-revolution

our website was created with wordpress and the Avada theme.
On the home site there is a space between the menu and the slider made with the Slider Revolution plugin. Can you tell us how to remove the spacing.

The space should be removed.

Comment: Enclosed the URL of our website https://www.scheidel-kunststoffe.de/

Answer (score 0):

This space is caused by a feature of the Avada theme: `Fusion Page Title Bar`.

See here: https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/headers/how-to-set-the-page-title-bar/

I don't personally know this theme, but I would check if this feature can be turned off for the homepage from the WordPress admin dashboard.

Otherwise, you can use custom `css` to hide it:

```
body.home .fusion-page-title-bar {
  display: none;
}
```